# Material Design Action Bar Example

Tags: android, material-design

Google Material design guidelines (https://material.google.com/motion/material-motion.html#material-motion-what-makes-a-good-transition) show the following as an example:

[image]

Is it using the built-in action bar? If so, how can I change the menu icon to a back arrow with such an animation? What happens if the action bar already has the back arrow for navigation to the previous activity? Is this something built into the framework?

Comment: Material Design guidelines really show a toolbar with a center title ? Do you have a link ? The burger to arrow animation is made with [ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html)

Comment: @AurélienLepage I just added the link into the question.